# Why does my window pop up on form load?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

This question concerns Oracle Forms 10g.

I have a form with two windows. The main form has a main canvas and two stacked canvases. On one of the stacked canvases there are keyboard navigable elements. I also have another window that is used as a calendar data selection. My problem is that when the form loads the calendar window is visible even though I have not explicitly told it be visible. I only want to show this window when a button is clicked so that the user can select a data from the calendar.

I have checked the main canvas and it DOES have navigable elements so I am not sure why the other form keeps popping up upon form load.

Any ideas? I am using Forms 10g

Thanks...

Comment: Did you not see the tags, "Forms", "Oracle"? Did you also not see where I said "I am using Forms 10g"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not tell the calendar window to explicitly not show up by using the built-in

```
 SET_WINDOW_PROPERTY('W_CALENDAR', VISIBLE, PROPERTY_FALSE);
```

On the calendar button on your first window you obviously have a `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger. Place below code at the beginning of the trigger to show the calendar `W_CALENDAR` window.

```
 SET_WINDOW_PROPERTY('W_CALENDAR', VISIBLE, PROPERTY_TRUE);
```